# Fill one column from a list based on the value of another column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a sheet where one column has values either `"delete"` or `empty`. If it is delete, I need to fill another column randomly from one of these value: `{"test1", "test2", "test3"}`. If it is empty, leave empty. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=IF(A1="delete",CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),"test1","test2","test3"),"")
```